# Swift - 'internal' modifier cannot be used in protocols

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, protocols, access-modifiers

I am getting compiler error when I am declaring function internal inside Swift protocol,

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    internal func test()
}
```

Error:

> 'internal' modifier cannot be used in protocols

Error is resolved if I remove the access modifier `internal` but I want to know why I am getting this error? As [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html) mentioned default access level will be internal in case if I do not explicitly mention any access level. So why it is producing comilers error when I am making it explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please scroll down in the linked article

> ## Protocols
>
> If you want to assign an explicit access level to a protocol type, **do so at the point that you define the protocol**. This enables you to create protocols that can only be adopted within a certain access context.
>
> The access level of each requirement within a protocol definition is automatically set to the same access level as the protocol. **You can’t set a protocol requirement to a different access level than the protocol it supports**. This ensures that all of the protocol’s requirements will be visible on any type that adopts the protocol.

It means you have to declare

```
internal protocol MyProtocol {
     func test()
}
```